# What's the issue with vcard duplicates?

Tags: format, vcf-vcard, duplication

No software I've seen is able to synchronize contacts between Outlook and my cell without creating **duplicates**. One would think that someone had synchronization in mind when they thought up the format. Is it impossible for programmers to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem using the native Nokia and Samsung software (and a free Nokia program I can't remember now), and I've found that none of them handle duplicates. To program around it, you could either copy one way, flush the source device, and copy back again, or you could copy, remove duplicates, and then copy back.